# Changing HTTP Version of HttpWebRequest (C#)

Tags: c#, http, rest, httpwebrequest

I understand this might be a very basic question.

Windows Azure needs me to use `HTTP 1.1` to call their REST API methods. However, when I call my methods, I get the following response from them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>UnsupportedHttpVersion</Code>
<Message>The HTTP version specified is not supported for this operation by the server.
RequestId:7cc39976-f022-4f15-b2a3-733fea600b95 Time:2012-01-12T05:52:44.1107398Z</Message>
<Version>1.0</Version><Via /></Error>
```

This is in C#, so the object I am using is a `HttpWebRequest`. I have tried looking under headers in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields but I haven't found any valuable information.

Can anyone show me the light? **:)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version of HTTP is not an HTTP header. To set HTTP version for `HttpWebRequest` use `HttpWebRequest.ProtocolVersion` property.

For description and sample code read in MSDN: [HttpWebRequest.ProtocolVersion Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.protocolversion.aspx)

Comment: @matt But according with MSDN default value of `ProtocolVersion` is HTTP1.1 and your problem with Windows Azure can be another.